# Ambiguous occurrence compilation error of custom data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I have a custom data type Person and Employee (DataTypesAPI.hs)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
data Person = Person {fName :: String
                     , lName :: String
                     } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToBSON, FromBSON)

data Employee = Employee {fName  :: String
                         , lName :: String
                         , id    :: String
                         } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON, ToBSON, FromBSON)
```

I have an instance of Employee (as e) and want to create Person instance from it so that fName and lName will be populated from Employee. Code snippet is (src/MyLib.hs)

```
import DataTypesAPI.hs (Employee(..), Person(..))
DataLink.map (\e -> Person (fName e) (lName e))
```

However, as both types have same attributes name ghc give compilation error

```
Ambiguous occurrence ‘last_commit_hash’
It could refer to either the field ‘fName’,
                                 imported from ‘FirstHaskellAPI’ at src/MyLib.hs:68:101-115
                              or the field ‘fName’,
                                 imported from ‘FirstHaskellAPI’ at src/MyLib.hs:68:53-98
```

In later part of my code I need both types. How to resolve such compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

Try disambiguating it using e.g.

```
DataLink.map (\e -> Person (fName e) (lName (e :: Employee)))
```

Comment: Changes that you had suggested still give me same error however when I change code `DataLink.map (\(e fn ln) -> Person fn ln)` it work for me.